# Exrjs4 tree panel set node parameter

Tags: extjs, parameters, extjs4, treenode

I have a problem here, maybe anyone can help me :)

I have a response from my PHP file, the main field that i will use is "id" and "kode_jabatan".
But i want is on click of the tree node i want to POST "kode_jabatan" not "id" field to the parameter.
Is there any trick or any documentation that i have missed?
The code is given below :

```
var treeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'func/mainFunction.php?get=menu',
            actionMethods: {
                create: 'POST',
                read: 'POST',
                update: 'POST',
                destroy: 'POST'
            }
        },
        nodeParam:'kode_jabatan',
        folderSort:true,
        root: {
            text: 'Struktur Organisasi',
            id: '(2010-01)',
            expanded: true
        }
});


Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
           store: treeStore,
           title: 'Menu Utama'
})
```

[image: screen shot for tree panel]

Comment: It's not clear what exactly are you asking. Please re-phrase it or provide some additional information

Answer (score 4):

Add the beforeload event to your treestore and you can access the current requesting node from the operation parameter, I have to do this in my code a lot when I need multiple parameters:

```
var treeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'func/mainFunction.php?get=menu',
            actionMethods: {
                create: 'POST',
                read: 'POST',
                update: 'POST',
                destroy: 'POST'
            }
        },
        nodeParam:'kode_jabatan',
        folderSort:true,
        root: {
            text: 'Struktur Organisasi',
            id: '(2010-01)',
            expanded: true
        },
        listeners: {
            beforeload: function(store, operation, eOpts){
            var kode_jabatan = operation.node.get("kode_jabatan");
            operation.params.node = kode_jabatan;
    }
});
```

basically you can add any params to the request that you want by setting new attributes in the operation.params.[whatever you want] object.

Comment: +1 ... @Reimius - what would the 'itemclick' event logic look like when using this logic, so the node value is passed to the store, and loaded correctly?  I'm using this function signature for the 'itemclick' event for my Ext.tree.TreePanel listener: itemclick: function(view, node, item, index, e) .. and you would only use this after the initial store load, for subsequent clicks only, right?

Comment: Not sure what itemclick has to do with sending data to the server, please clarify?